# PHP: Sort an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key-value

Please how do i sort the below array

```
Array
(
    'ben' => 1.0,
    'ken' => 2.0,
    'sam' => 1.5
)
```

to

```
Array
(
    'ken' => 2.0,
    'sam' => 1.5,
    'ben' => 1.0
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: why you have used `'` near numbers like `'ben' => 1.0',`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
<?php
$my_array = array('ben' => 1.0, 'ken' => 2.0, 'sam' => 1.5);

arsort($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>
```

The `arsort()` function sorts an array by the values in reverse order. The values keep their original keys.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole manual section dedicated to such things:

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

edit: specifically, `arsort()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = Array(
'ben' => 1.0,
'ken' => 2.0,
'sam' => 1.5
)    
$sorted = asort($arr);
$reversed = rsort($sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the array keys where not retained

Comment: That's strange.  According to the documentation, asort maintains the keys. Oh, I see, rsort is mixing it up again. hmmmm

Comment: Yes, rsort is the bad guy there. asort() works but i still had to use array_reverse() to get a DESC order. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you use regular PHP array sorting functions, you'll lose your array keys. I think the shortest path to what you want is something like this:

```
$array = array("ben" => "1.0", "ken" => "2.0", "sam" => "1.5");
array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC);
print_r($array);
```

Make sure that all of your array values are either strings or numbers, otherwise the result will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function should work:

`sort($theArray, SORT_NUMERIC);`

### Update

I didn't notice you wanted it in reverse; in that case use [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php).

Comment: This sorts low to high. Poster wants high to low. Thus rsort();

Comment: Yeah just saw that... i need to pay more attention :-) Gave you both +1